# Storing images in iOS: best option?

Tags: ios, database, image, file, sqlite

I have an iOS app that makes use of an `sqlite` database. I need to persist several pictures I enable the user to take and save, what should be the most appropiate way to handle that? To store them into `Documents` as `jpeg` image files? To store them into the database? I've found some posts dealing with both that options, but I'd like to know which one is the most correct or the most recommended...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either approach. Like neilco, I would lean more towards storing the images as files in your documents directory and saving paths to them in your database.

You can also store them as BLOBs in your database. If you do that, make sure to make the image BLOBs separate entities, and only load them when needed. That way you don't bog down reading of your "normal" database entities with image data.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to store the images in `Documents` and create a record in the database with the path to the image.